# Что делает cout << " " << endl в C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << " ВВВВВВВВВВВВВВВВ " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это из вопросов на собеседовании на должность старшего программиста?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Директора, не меньше!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я думаю, что директоров спрашивают про таблицу сложения.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ответ на этот вопрос есть в любом учебнике по С++.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: В двоичной системе!

Comment: Попробуйте перейти в Linux, возможно кучу подобных вопросов, которые на первый взгляд кажутся абсолютно дурацкими, задавать вообще не придется.

Comment: @avp: Вы зовёте на линукс человека, который не прочитал ни одной книги по C++ — думаете, он будет читать маны?

Comment: @VladD, вопрос-то у него судя по комментарию `по какой причине может не выводить ? просто открывается консоль` к ответу о другом, просто ужасно сформулирован.

Comment: @avp: Ну, для того, чтобы описать конкретно видимую проблему, не нужно быть опытным программистом. С подходом «скажу что-нибудь, придут умные мальчики, разберутся и всё за меня сделают» программист не выживет.

Comment: @VladD, да дело ведь не в нем, а в тех из нас, которые не могут сходу суть дела схватить.

Comment: @avp: Я не смог. Ну и автор вопроса должен хоть чуть-чуть стараться сотрудничать, а не ждать, пока из него клещами вытянут информацию.

Answer (score 5):

Вывести на консоль строку `" ВВВВВВВВВВВВВВВВ "` естественно без апострофов.

Comment: по какой причине может не выводить ? просто открывается консоль

Comment: @viktor Может быть консоль просто быстро закрывается? Вам надо тогда в конце программы поставить задержку.

Comment: Или если открывается консоль и просто "висит" с чёрным экраном - то выключите/настройте Avast :)